# How to get visible tds using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

how to get tds which are visible. I am trying this statement but this returns only hidden td's

> find("table td:hidden")

How do i get "not hidden" tds using jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

```
var visible_tds = $('table td:visible');
```